# module not found (conditional imports) with py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I have a little problem with py2app
when I build the app, I have this error

```
Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * Image (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app-0.9-py3.4.egg/py2app/recipes/PIL/prescript.py)
 * java (platform)
 * java.lang (platform)
```

I guess it is a path problem with my python 3, but I'm not sure
TY for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you build your app like this:

```
python3 setup.py myapp
```

and are using py2app 0.9?

If you are trying

```
python3 setup.py myapp -A
```

does this work? Using aliases only seems to work in most cases, but this doesn't help if you want to deploy your app to other machines.

Instead, explicitly tell py2app to include your packages:

```
python3 setup.py myapp --packages=PIL
```

This would properly include your PIL or Pillow module. Should work with the other modules, too.